# ACF Database Query $wpdb->prepare

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following which works great but i want to also add a check for and ACF field called 'category'.

```
function get_nearby_locations( $lat, $lng, $distance, $company, $category) {
global $wpdb;

$earth_radius = 3959;

$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ID,
        p.post_title,
        latitude.meta_value as locLat,
        longitude.meta_value as locLong,
        ( %d * acos(
        cos( radians( %s ) )
        * cos( radians( latitude.meta_value ) )
        * cos( radians( longitude.meta_value ) - radians( %s ) )
        + sin( radians( %s ) )
        * sin( radians( latitude.meta_value ) )
        ) )
        AS distance
    FROM $wpdb->posts p
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta latitude ON p.ID = latitude.post_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta longitude ON p.ID = longitude.post_id
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND p.post_title LIKE '%$company%' 
    AND p.post_type = 'supplier'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND latitude.meta_key = '$category'
    AND latitude.meta_key = 'latitude'
    AND longitude.meta_key = 'longitude'
    HAVING distance < %s
    ORDER BY distance ASC",
    $earth_radius,
    $category,
    $lat,
    $lng,
    $lat,
    $distance
);

$nearbyLocations = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

if ( $nearbyLocations ) {
    return $nearbyLocations;
}
}
```

All attempts to add another Inner join make the query fail and it returns no results. If i remove the following, it works with $company (Post title) and Postcode search.

Comment: So show us the code with the new inner join otherwise we have no idea what you have done

Comment: And what is the error message? And Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: Its just pulling no results through.

Comment: add `'%$sector%'` as an argument as both `%` are conflicting with placeholders in `prepare()` function. So replace `AND sector.meta_key = '%$sector%'` with `AND sector.meta_key = '%s'` and add `'%$sector%'`as a coma separated argument after `$lat,`. Also note that `$lng`and `$lat` should be inverted.

Comment: Thank you, i've updated my function in original question - still no joy though. What am i missing?